# Override rake test:units runner

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently decided to write a simple test runtime profiler for our Rails 3.0 app's test suite.  It's a very simple (read: hacky) script that adds each test's time to a global, and then outputs the result at the end of the run:

```
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'

module ProfilingHelper

  def self.included mod
    $test_times ||= []

    mod.class_eval do
      setup :setup_profiling
      def setup_profiling
        @test_start_time = Time.now
      end

      teardown :teardown_profiling
      def teardown_profiling
        @test_took_time = Time.now - @test_start_time
        $test_times << [name, @test_took_time]
      end
    end

  end

end

class ProfilingRunner < Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner
  def finished(elapsed_time)
    super
    tests = $test_times.sort{|x,y| y[1] <=> x[1]}.first(100)
    output("Top 100 slowest tests:")
    tests.each do |t|
      output("#{t[1].round(2)}s: \t #{t[0]}")
    end
  end
end

Test::Unit::AutoRunner::RUNNERS[:profiling] = proc do |r|
  ProfilingRunner
end
```

This allows me to run the suites like so `rake test:xxx TESTOPTS="--runner=profiling"` and get a list of Top 100 tests appended to the end of the default runner's output. It works great for `test:functionals` and `test:integration`, and even for `test:units TEST='test/unit/an_example_test.rb'`. But if I do not specify a test for `test:units`, the TESTOPTS appears to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In classic **SO** style, I found the answer after articulating clearly to myself, so here it is:

When run without `TEST=/test/unit/blah_test.rb`, `test:units TESTOPTS=` needs a `--` before its contents. So the solution in its entirety is simply:

`rake test:units TESTOPTS='-- --runner=profiling'`

Comment: Why this is needed under this circumstance is beyond me, so if someone else could help me find that answer it would be greatly appreciated.